# Bootstrap 3 Stateful button not working with $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

While playing with [stateful buttons in Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons), I encountered a problem. As shown in snippet#2 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahidsadik/YCst4/1024/)), I am expecting the "Loading state" button will change its label to "Loading", and then will change itself back to "Loading state"; this version works. But, snippet#3 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahidsadik/YCst4/1023/)) does not work.

Can anyone explain why it is like that?

#### Snippet#1: HTML code

```html
<button id="loading-example-btn" data-loading-text="Loading..." 
    class="btn btn-primary">Loading state</button>
```

#### Snippet#2: JS code that works

```js
(function ($) {
    $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.button('loading');
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.button('reset');
        }, 1000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

#### Snippet#3: JS code that does not work

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () { //<-- this is causing the button not to work
        $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.button('loading');
            setTimeout(function () {
                btn.button('reset');
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

### Edit

Thanks @Hüseyin BABAL. He helped me realize that I was using an incompatible Bootstrap CSS (I borrowed from someone else's jsfiddle). Once I fixed it ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahidsadik/YCst4/1026/)), was taken care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to incompability of bootstrap js and jquery version. Update it to bootstrap 3.x. or downgrade jquery to 1.8.3

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

You can see working demo here for bootstrap 3.x : http://jsfiddle.net/KYR64/1/

You can see working demo here for downgrade jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/KYR64/2/